# css layout width of <body> reduced compared to <html>

Tags: html, css, layout

My web page content is being shifted to the right, when I debug using chrome it shows the width of tags as :

```
<html> : 1280px
<body> : 1264px
<all my divs> : 1264px
```

Although I am setting width to 100%.  It matters not which browser I use.

(yes I have a small screen)

Comment: Have you cleared the margins and padding on the body element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a borwser reset for the css you can avoid things like this.. This one is my favs
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
```